# I would like to extract a subvector based on an elementwise condition

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab vector

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and would like to extract all values based on a boolean function, for example all even numbers. Something like this:

```
result = selector(a, is_even);
% result is now [2,4,6,8,10]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Furthermore, suppose I have a matrix

```
A = [1,2,3 
     4,5,6,
     7,8,9]
```

is there also a way to select rows that start with a value in the first column which is even?

```
result = selector(A, is_even);
% result is now a matrix with one row [4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

First question:

```
result = a(mod(a,2)==0);
```

Second question:

```
result = A(mod(A(:,1),2)==0,:);
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Logical indexing**](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) is your friend.

Simply use:

```
a(mod(a,2)==0)
```

Similarly, `a(mod(a,2)==1)` will give you all odd values.

---

Once you know this, you can easily solve your second question in the similar way. :P